# T-SQL create table statement will not accept variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why can I not use a variable to name a new table?

As a beginning SQL project, I'm making a personal finance database. Each account will have a corresponding table in the database. There is also a table listing all the current accounts. See (simplified) code sample below:

```
CREATE TABLE accountList
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    [Name] NCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    [Active] BIT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO accountList(name, active)
VALUES
     ('Bank_One_Checking', 1);  

CREATE TABLE Bank_One_Checking
(
[Id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [payee] NCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [category] NCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
[amount] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
)
```

This code works. I want to set the account name to a variable (so it can be passed as a parameter to a stored procedure). See code below:

```
DECLARE @accountName nchar(30);
SET @accountName = 'Bank_One_Savings';

INSERT INTO accountList(name, active)
VALUES
    (@accountName, 1);

CREATE TABLE @accountName
(
    [Id] BIGINT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY, 
    [payee] NCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [category] NCHAR(30) NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
    [amount] INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0.00
)
```

Line 6 in that code (CREATE TABLE @accountName) produces an error

> Incorrect syntax near @accountName, expecting '.', 'ID', or 'QUOTEID'.

Why won't it insert the variable into the command?

Comment: Dynamic SQL will work, if nothing else.

Comment: you cannot use a variable for table and column names, for that you need to use dynamic sql

Comment: Don't do this. It's bad design. That's why it's hard to do. You should have an Accounts table, and a Transactions table: each row of the Transactions table should reference an Account.ID.

Comment: You cannot use a variable for the table name in queries. A better option would be to have _one_ table and a column to distinguish the bank.  Mutliple tables with the same structure and purpose is generally a bad design.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the advice. It's interesting how what looks like a bug in the code can reveal a fundamental flaw in design.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL doesn't allow tables to be variables. You could use dynamic SQL, if you like, but I strongly recommend against it.

Your code has several flaws. You should learn not only to fix them but why they are wrong.

- You need a "master" table, where `AccountName` is a column. Multiple tables with the same structure is almost always a sign of poor database design.
- Strings should be designed using `VARCHAR()` or `NVARCHAR()`, unless they are short or known to be the same length (say an account number that is always 15 characters). Fixed-length strings just waste space.
- I find it unlikely that a column named `category` would be unique in such a table. It seems to violate what uniqueness means.
- Integers are not appropriate for monetary amounts in most of the world (use `decimal` or `money`). And, they shouldn't be initialized to constants with a decimal point.